# Copy Constructor not working for Circular Queue?

Tags: c++, queue, copy-constructor

Im trying to make a copy of an object, which is a circular queue. My Enqueue and Dequeue work correctly, but whenever I do this, I get a runtime error.

```
CQUEUE j = k;
```

The output window says that my copy constructor is recursive on all control paths?  Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong please?  Here is my copy constructor, along with the overloaded assignment operator.

```
CQUEUE::CQUEUE(const CQUEUE& original)
{
(*this) = original;
}


void CQUEUE::operator=(CQUEUE w)
{
qnode *p = w.front;
(*this).front = new qnode;
(*this).back = front;

while(p -> next != w.back)
{
  back -> num = p -> num;
  p = p -> next;
  back -> next = new qnode;
  back = back -> next;
}

back -> num = p -> num;
p = p -> next;
back -> next = new qnode;
back = back -> next;
back -> num = p -> num;

back -> next = front;
front -> prev = back;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(*this) = original;
```

The compiler is making this line call the copy constructor instead of your = operator, because your = operator currently takes a **non-const, by-value** CQUEUE. Instead, your = operator should look like this:

```
void CQUEUE::operator=(const CQUEUE& w)
```

Then your copy constructor will call your operator = instead. Alternatively, make it more explicit:

```
CQUEUE::CQUEUE(const CQUEUE& original)
{
    Copy(original);
}

void CQUEUE::operator=(const CQUEUE& w)
{
    Copy(w);
}

void CQUEUE::Copy(const CQUEUE& other)
{
    // All your copy code here
}
```

EDIT: Yes, you're correct, you still do need a copy constructor.

Comment: That would be awesome, but dont i have to make my own since im trying to use = on my own created objects?

Comment: Oh, yes, you're correct. You do still need a copy c'tor. The real issue is the signature of your operator =. I think an explicit Copy() function makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the assignment operator function to  and be careful about self-assignment

```
void CQUEUE::operator=(const CQUEUE& w)
{
   if (this == &w)
        return *this;

   //Paste your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it backward, somewhat.

In general, the assignment operator is more complex than the copy constructor because it needs to properly dispose of the held resources on top of moving to the new value.

It is normally easier to compose a complex system out of simple parts rather than create a *do-it-all* part and express simple systems on top of it. In your context, it means than it is easier to create an assignment operator from a copy constructor.

Therefore, just write the copy constructor fully:

```
CQUEUE(CQUEUE const& c) { ... }
```

Then write a routine to swap (exchange the contents) of two `CQUEUE` instances:

```
void swap(CQUEUE& c) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(front, c.front);
    swap(back, c.back);
}
```

And finally, build the assignment operator out of them:

```
CQUEUE& operator=(CQUEUE c) { // copy
    this->swap(c);
    return *this;
}
```

This idiom is known as *copy-and-swap* (yes, very creative!).

*Note: bonus note, if you have a move constructor, then it becomes a move-and-swap for free.*

Comment: although correct, this method of crafting overloaded assignment operator forces an unnecessary copy in self-assignment scenario.

Comment: @Chethan: the question is, is self-assignment so frequent that it's worth sacrificing some maintenability for ?

Comment: @Mattheiu, we have no idea of the cost of allocation of such objects. So I assumed them to be costly (say, in embedded systems) to point that out. Otherwise, the solution is very elegant :)

Comment: @Chethan: I was not challenging the cost of the assignment, but the frequency of self-assignment itself. I often see it mentionned here and there, but since I have never seen it appearing in a profile report of any of the applications I worked on, as far as I am concerned this is a typical *premature optimization*.

Comment: @Kobor42: That is not how it works, however you can ask the moderators to merge the two questions together.